# Pipenv can't install Twisted on Python 3.8

Tags: python, twisted, pipenv, python-3.8

I originally ran into this issue using Pipenv to install the news-please package, but I've narrowed the issue down specifically to the combination of the Twisted package and Python 3.8. This pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
Twisted = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Results in this error:

```
Pipfile.lock (2aac7a) out of date, updating to (42c109)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (2aac7a)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (2aac7a)…
An error occurred while installing twisted==19.10.0 --hash=sha256:0f39698c2aac318032ed4fe95e28ee2bd7d72327c2f6927139811ad403770885 --hash=sha256:1f0919a0363b4fbed5def5315383db36fd581464bca80290764f8c4465e91c04 --hash=sha256:257dbc78e72bc69c2970035fc74df54b04573d5ddd380251a8a23f74d619db03 --hash=sha256:3f651c52ad78cc5a643f61e3b786a6b5c9b4ee68eced975c04fdf6b02026f470 --hash=sha256:58b581ae4eee5a831aac9d03edc331d662fa028f601015bb3df47f8704bfe876 --hash=sha256:611ef7696d406605962d9a7b040d357f3e91df20cf75c0b06e350947f541538b --hash=sha256:6338e5b987e95c94360acb14e78b41097be9b45d44d15a68060db9c3bf89e102 --hash=sha256:776c65270b57ac074d5b7a471142f434b0ac5a8b39d9c974769c855c32abfd91 --hash=sha256:8b2f7f4dded5ad02931bed38042e55329d1e4919b63078f5a29f05502a163f1d --hash=sha256:97f8a76632bf051a27179337fe937df315920a08e9bd146126e0126629db3721 --hash=sha256:a1de7598ce977943b3edbcc0a7d2112f134cc1b98b2fd7e348ee9e0bef092e50 --hash=sha256:d145c418a46f8a7021030a3246b9e5111f64531278e5252f2073f23c1661c8be --hash=sha256:d53e1f883bc429b14fd2999d355352974f9d7b4ae7554154bbfe3f90aecede5f --hash=sha256:d9037ff5e07909b1d31f81db71a3bbc8227ba1ed20c87332bdb2eb48e55f326e --hash=sha256:ef1396d1680d6a1ae6dff293d778755c8e10d471f286aff678877b2cee235d42 --hash=sha256:f1fe9139fdcf7721d308e36c51cf975474678a8241a9799af02a7bb1c531b722 --hash=sha256:f28355e61ce0b5c1ce47784522022322cc5059c8ed80638e0caae8c7301e1705 --hash=sha256:f7cc56a45c983e4e48601fbeec879b62c740cb848c75164f69a48ac0c6e8a21c! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 10/10 — 00:00:03
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/fischer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/fischer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/fischer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/fischer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/fischer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: []
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twisted==19.10.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-bj65cloq-requirements/pipenv-3idjau65-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)', 'ERROR: No matching distribution found for twisted==19.10.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-bj65cloq-requirements/pipenv-3idjau65-requirement.txt (line 1))']
```

When running `pipenv install`. Trying specific versions of Twisted doesn't seem to help. I can successfully install and use the package with `pip3` or by installing from git, but would prefer to use the default pypi index because it simplifies my docker build.

Comment: You're running Python 3.6 and asking for a Twisted release for Python 3.8.  Even if this worked, it shouldn't.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone it looks like pip is using python 3.6 to install pipenv, but I don't think that's related. I've seen the same failure in a docker build that used python 3.8 to install pipenv. I'm also not clear if this is actually an issue since everything in pipenv runs in a virtual environment.